# PHP can I call unexistent function with call_user_func

Tags: php, overloading

Here it what I want to do:
I have an object

```
class TestObject {
      public function __call($name,$args){
        if($name == 'somemethod'){
          print "Yesssss!!!!!!";
        }
      }
}
```

than in code i'm calling this method like this:

```
$obj = new TestObject()
$obj->somemethod()  // should work according to http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call
call_user_func(array('myobject','somemethod')) // this does not work!!!
```

Is there any way to get the last example to work?

Comment: Have you tried `array($obj, 'somemethod');`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
call_user_func(array($obj,'somemethod'));
```

or

```
$method = 'somemethod';
$obj->$method();
```

Comment: call_user_func(array($obj,'somemethod')); - this wont call unexistent method

Comment: It does call the '__call' method if it doesn't exist.

Comment: $obj->$method(); - the problem is that I cannot use this type of calling. i need to use call_user_func

Comment: Hmm, yes it does call __call method in test script.

Answer (score 0):

```
$obj_name = 'myobject';
$method_name = 'somemethod';
${$obj_name}->${$method->name()};
```