# PHP : Method defined in _call and called with call_user_func_array

Tags: php

I have a similar question to this one : [PHP can I call unexistent function with call_user_func](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923235/php-can-i-call-unexistent-function-with-call-user-func)

I need to call a method defined width __call but i don't know how many parameter to pass. So I am using this :

```
call_user_func_array(array($object, $method_name), $arguments);
```

But it doesn't work.
Actually, this works :

```
$object->$method_name();
```

But i don't know how to pass parameter by an other way that call_user_func_array...

I wan't something like :

```
$object->$method_name($arguments[0], $arguments[1], $arguments[2] /*,... until no more args*/);
```

An idea ?
Thank you

Comment: Please show us how you defined the `__call()` method, by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44116002/edit), because it should just work.

Comment: _But it doesn't work_ Really, what DOES it do, error, sparks, leakage???

Comment: I'm so stupid... it was in order to get a value. so actually it did just nothing. Now it seems logical for me to put a return before my call_user_func... An d you know what ? it works ! Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

This is perfectly possible. I don't know your code, but here's a quick test I put together to make sure it works:

```
class Foo {
    function _bar($arg1, $arg2) {
        print_r(func_get_args());
    }

    function __call($name, $args) {
        call_user_func_array([$this, '_'.$name], $args);
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$func = 'bar';

call_user_func_array([$foo, $func], ['1', '2']);

// Array
// (
//     [0] => 1
//     [1] => 2
// )
```

This tries to call the function `Foo::bar()` which doesn't exist, so it ends up in `Foo::__call()`, which then calls `Foo::_bar()`.